# How to use NLTK to generate random paragraphs

Tags: python, nltk

Am trying to build a testunit to stress test a very large implementation for publication management. I thought of using NLTK to generate paragraphs, about different things and random titles for articles.

Would NLTK be capable of doing such a thing? I want to try to make each article unique, to test different layout sizing. I also want to do the same with subjects.

*P.S Am required to generate 1+ million article which will be used to test many things in the end (performance, search, layout..etc)*

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: does it have to be NLTK? I have used other means in the past to achieve the outcome you need

Comment: no off course, it can be anything.. but, I was under the impression that only NLTK can do that. but, if you have any alternative, by all means

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this. It takes phrases from Noam Chomsky and generates random paragraphs. You can change the feedstock text to whatever you want. The more text you use the better, of course.

```
# List of LEADINs to buy time.
leadins = """To characterize a linguistic level L,
        On the other hand,
        This suggests that
        It appears that
        Furthermore """

# List of SUBJECTs chosen for maximum professorial macho.
subjects = """ the notion of level of grammaticalness
        a case of semigrammaticalness of a different sort
        most of the methodological work in modern linguistics
        a subset of English sentences interesting on quite independent grounds
        the natural general principle that will subsume this case """

#List of VERBs chosen for autorecursive obfuscation.
verbs = """can be defined in such a way as to impose
        delimits
        suffices to account for
        cannot be arbitrary in
        is not subject to """


# List of OBJECTs selected for profound sententiousness.

objects = """ problems of phonemic and morphological analysis.
        a corpus of utterance tokens upon which conformity has been defined by the paired utterance test.
        the traditional practice of grammarians.
        the levels of acceptability from fairly high (e.g. (99a)) to virtual gibberish (e.g. (98d)).
        a stipulation to place the constructions into these various categories.
        a descriptive fact.
        a parasitic gap construction."""

import textwrap, random
from itertools import chain, islice, izip
from time import sleep

def chomsky(times=1, line_length=72):
    parts = []
    for part in (leadins, subjects, verbs, objects):
        phraselist = map(str.strip, part.splitlines())
        random.shuffle(phraselist)
        parts.append(phraselist)
    output = chain(*islice(izip(*parts), 0, times))
    return textwrap.fill(' '.join(output), line_length)

print chomsky()
```

which returned for me:

> This suggests that a case of semigrammaticalness of a different sort
>   is not subject to a corpus of utterance tokens upon which conformity
>   has been defined by the paired utterance test.

and for a title, of course you can do

```
chomsky().split('\n')[0]
```